When writing a blurb, can I refer to my characters using descriptors instead of their names?
I’m writing a blurb for a novel with three main characters. Can I refer to them as “a young man”, “his lady friend”, and “the nurse” instead of their names?

You are accurately describing the way log-lines refer to characters when summarizing the plot of your novel. It works well when used near the beginning of the blurb, when the resolution is at its lowest.
Later in the blurb, if it is longish — multi paragraph —- then using the protagonists and important characters names would likely be appropriate for clarity and engagement — making them seem more real.

I always advise to:

look at blurbs for similar books and
observe yourself when you buy books.

That is, which blurbs make you want to open a book and read the first pages? And how are blurbs written in your genre by the marketing professionals who understand what sells?
To write good blurbs, you need to read a lot of good blurbs.

That said, I just randomly pulled a few books from my shelf and they all give the names of the protagonist(s) and what role they play in the story and for each other.
Commonly, a blurb is a brief summary of the story up to and including the inciting incident, hinting at the rising action and the climax to come. It names the major characters, explains who they are, what sets the story in motion, and what the goals and stakes are.
Readers will be more inclined to open a book if they are offered a character they can identify with, and identification better works with a name.
But there are exceptions. Hard science fiction, for example, sometimes has blurbs without names, because the "protagonist" of the story isn't a person but a phenomenon, an event, or an undertaking. So the first thing you need to do is understand what it is you are selling to your audience. And that must be presented in your blurb.
